# What is the default password for the MaaS Image?

Tags: maas

What is the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS image password?

I installed it as a node of Ubuntu maas with cobbler. It retrieved packages over Internet and installed it. I have just ssh public key, but I do not have password or other credentials. Can I obtain it from somewhere else?

Answer (score 5):

Your SSH key should be used for access. The SSH keys that you've set in MAAS will all be put on the newly installed node, in the `ubuntu` user account. You should be able to get into the machine with:

```
ssh ubuntu@${address-of-node}
```

Then use `sudo` to do things as `root`, as usual, though I don't think it'll prompt you for a password.

Comment: The problem still exists. My MAAS have two users and two public keys are added in webUI. After installation, ssh ubuntu@node-address prompts for password. It seems these two public keys are not in authorized_keys in /.ssh/. Any comments?

Comment: The result after installation is something like this:     Ubuntu 12.04 LTS client-image ttyl 
client-image login: ec2: ec2: ############################# ec2:  BEGIN SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS  ec2: 1024 98:....:11 root@client-image (DS A) ec2: 256 7a:.....:2f root@client-image (ECD SA) ec2: 2048 B....:16:2b root@client-image (RS A) ec2:  END SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS  ec2: ######################  BEGIN SSH HOST KEY KEYS  ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZ....450= root@client-image ssh-rsa AAAA.......Ur3Hc5ToJZ root@client-image  END SSH HOST KEY KEYS

Comment: A work around for my case: boot the node with Ubuntu live and mount the disk. Then edit .ssh specially authorized_keys file of root and ubuntu user as you want. :D

Comment: It may be worth noting that the node's status must be "Allocated to <user>". That is, you'll need to `Start` the node. If it's just "Ready", MAAS doesn't know whose SSH key should be authorized.

Answer (score 1):

Same here with root user.
What's the point in using MAAS if after install you have live cd to install your keys?

**edit**
As a workaround
I set a password for the ubuntu user in this path:

```
/var/lib/cobbler/kickstarts/maas.preseed

d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password <MY-CRYPTED-PASSWORD>
```

After logging in `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys`, was empty.